# Configuration for Java binding for ZeroMQ (0MQ) with no root privileges on Linux

Tags: jzmq

I am a novice with zeroMQ and I am stuck at binding ØMQ with java on a server running CentOS release 5.9.

Unfortunately, I **do not** have super user/**root** privileges on the server and am trying to install ØMQ as a normal user with restricted privileges. I have installed ØMQ by following instructions on http://www.zeromq.org/area:download

> ```
> Make sure that libtool, autoconf, automake are installed.
> Check whether uuid-dev package, uuid/e2fsprogs RPM or equivalent on your system is installed.
> Unpack the .tar.gz source archive.
> Run ./configure, followed by make.
> ```

Could not run the following obviously

> ```
> To install ØMQ system-wide run sudo make install.
> On Linux, run sudo ldconfig after installing ØMQ.
> ```

Then I attempted to install jzmq.

1. Cloned [git clone https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq.git]
2. Ran autogen.sh
3. Ran configure

At this point I get the following error

```
checking for ZeroMQ... no
checking zmq.h usability... no
checking zmq.h presence... no
checking for zmq.h... no
configure: error: cannot find zmq.h
```

As a result of the above error I am not able to run java tests and get error "no jzmq in java.library.path".

Can anybody help/direct me to how to get java binding for zeromq work when you dont have root privileges to install it? Its difficult to get IT department to install a new software on servers.

Appreciate your help.

Note: I do not have write permissions to /usr directory

Thanks
GBP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be overcome by adding --with-zeromq=/home/user/zeromq  (installation directory of zeromq)

```
./configure --with-zeromq=/home/user/zeromq
```

Other steps include
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/zeromq/lib

Answer (score 2):

You can also use JeroMQ (https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) which is a pure Java implementation of ZeroMQ

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if jeromq is fit for production use yet?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491000/is-jeromq-production-ready). I'm using it in a development environment and have had no problems.

Comment: It does not support multicast messaging, which actually is a key feature ..
https://code.google.com/p/fast-cast/ is a pure java reliable multicast implementation, but its not related to 0mq

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by running autogen.sh on OEL 6 then running configure / compiling / installing on CentOS 5.9.  I briefly looked into why autogen.sh was failing and the problem was the tool chain was too old.  Since I had a more up-to-date system with a modern tool chain available running autogen.sh on something other than CentOS 5 was the easiest path for me.  I'm sure it works fine with other modern Linux variants, I had OEL 6 at my finger tips.

I also did not have access to a standard directory for installation.  To get that working I added zmq.jar to my class path, and the run-time linker needed to be able to find the zeromq and jzmq run-time libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on CentOS 6.5 and found that you need to install "gcc-c++" for this to work.

I used the following to install dependencies:

yum -y install jdk zeromq-devel unzip libtool gcc autoconf automake gcc-c++ python

Note that "jdk" comes from our private repository and it's same what can be downloaded from java.com

The following public repositories are installed on server:

atomic

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up having this same issue, and the following script worked for me, where I installed zeromq into ~ (so that I have ~/lib contains libzmq.a  libzmq.la  libzmq.so  libzmq.so.3  libzmq.so.3.1.0  pkgconfig)

```
./autogen.sh ./configure --prefix=$HOME \   #because you don't have root privileges

   --with-zeromq=$HOME --includedir=$HOME/include/ --libdir=$HOME/lib/ 
./make 
./make -n install
```

#to check to see if it installs it to the right location

`make install`